# How to put a WebView in a frame

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have a page, "A", with a WebView in it. I'm trying to put page A inside a frame in Page B. However, the WebView doesn't seem to be appearing through the frame. Please help, thank you.

**A.xaml:**

```
<WebView />
```

**B.xaml:**

```
<muxc:TabView x:Name="TabView" AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddButtonClick" />
```

**B.xaml.cpp:**

```
private void TabView_AddButtonClick(TabView sender, object args)
{
    sender.TabItems.Add(CreateNewTab(sender.TabItems.Count));
}
    
private TabViewItem CreateNewTab()
{
    TabViewItem newItem = new TabViewItem();

    newItem.Header = $"Document";
    Frame frame = new Frame();

    frame.Navigate(typeof(B))

    newItem.Content = frame;

    return newItem;
}
```

Comment: sample of your code or something ?

Comment: @ChiKa LiO Sure, I just updated the post.

Comment: I test the code in my side and the WebView works well through the frame of page B. Could you please tell me if the WebView works in page A?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Webview works on page A. It is worth noting that the frame is in a TabView.

Comment: Could you please show me the detailed code about your WebView in page A?  By testing, if we do not set the Height property of WebView, it may cause the issue mentioned by you. It is better if you could check if you have set the Height property of WebView.

Comment: Has your problem been resolved? If the problem is not resolved, please feel free and contact us.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, it has been solved. Thank you!